# PHP - If a word contains a certain string replace it

Tags: php

I have an array with bad strings that i want to replace in certain words, currently i wrote this code to manage this but its not working as it should:

```
public function _clean_filename($fn)
{
    if($fn === '')
        return;

    foreach((array)$_filename_bad_chars as $bad)
    {
        if(strpos($fn, $bad))
        {
            str_replace($bad, '', $fn);
        }
    }
    return $fn;
}
```

Simptom: When i input a word with bad strings in it the function returns nothing.

How should i rewrite this code to make it functional?

Comment: So where is `$_filename_bad_chars` defined. Not in the scope of this function thats for sure

Comment: Its declared as a public array in the same class :)

Comment: Well then try `$this->_filename_bad_chars` and loose the `(array)` casting unless of course its not an array??

Comment: Nothing changed... the function returns the same result.

Comment: `str_replace($bad, '', $fn);` returns a string, you are dumping it into the ether, see @Forseti answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems that:

1. `$_filename_bad_chars` should be `$this->_filename_bad_chars`
2. `str_replace($bad, '', $fn);` should be `$fn = str_replace($bad, '', $fn);`

Comment: Lol, i feel like a total noob right now! Thank you very much guys!

Comment: the loop is also surplus, as `str_replace` accepts arrays

Answer (score 2):

you can simplify the whole method:

```
public function _clean_filename($fn)
{        
    return str_replace($this->_file_bad_chars, '', $fn);
}
```

`str_replace` accepts arrays for all parameters, and given an empty string for `subject` will return an empty string

also, your use of a leading underscore for a public method is odd!